# how do I properly re-prompt a statement in mario.c?

Tags: cs50

im having problems with my code. at first, it would reject the answer inputted and stopped the code. but as soon as I added a return function. the code would abruptly end. what should  I do?

here is my code. it's in C

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    
    do
    {
        height = get_int("pick a number, any number!: ");
    }
    while ( height < 1 && height > 8);
           
    // here is my problem
    return (-3);
    
    if ( height > 0 && height < 9)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for ( int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            if ( counter != height)
            {
                for ( int spaces = (height - 1) - counter; spaces > 0; spaces--)
                {
                    printf (" ");
                }
                for ( int hashes = 0; hashes <= counter; hashes++)
                {
                    printf ("#");
                }
                printf("  ");
                for ( int hashes = 0; hashes <= counter; hashes++)
                {
                    printf ("#");
                }
                printf ("\n");
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm kinda new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your do-while loop. You should say

```
while (height < 1 || height > 8)
```

Your current code says

```
while (height < 1 && height > 8)
```

which makes no sense because the height can never be both smaller than 1 and greater than 8.